# How to assign values to variables from a dropdown menu selection in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am creating a dropdown menu that contains the names of companies that have pre-negotiated discounts for reselling hardware and services. I have the respective companies and their discounts arranged in rows (company, product discount% (pd), service discount% (sd)).

How do I assign the respective % to pd and sd variables based on the selection of the company from a dropdown menu?

I want this to dynamically update the values derived from the formulas referencing these variables as the selections are changed by the users.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=VLOOKUP()`

e.g
`VLOOKUP(A1, A2:B10, 2, FALSE)`

- `A1` is the cell where the company is selected.
- `A2:B10` is the list of companies with the according discounts.
- `2` means that the second column of the matching line is the output.
- `FALSE` means that the match has to be exact. `TRUE` would be the closest match.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1